# Can not create table, errno: 150

Tags: sql, mysql, maven, mysql-error-1005

What is bad in these queries for creating tables?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CVM`.`CANDIDATE` (
  `ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `FULL_NAME` VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL ,
  `HR_INTERVIEW_DATE` DATE NULL ,
  `JOB_SEARCH_STATUS` TINYINT(1)  NULL ,
  `REFERENCES_OPTIONAL` TEXT NULL ,
  `AVAILABILITY` TEXT NULL ,
  `LOCATION` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `TRIP` TEXT NULL ,
  `INTERPERSONAL_RISKS` TEXT NULL ,
  `TECHNICAL_INTERVIEW_DATE` DATE NULL ,
  `EXPERIENCE_IT` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `EXPERIENCE_JAVA` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `ENGLISH_CHECK_DATE` DATE NULL ,
  `ENGLISH_READINESS_DIALOGUE` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `ENGLISH_TIME_IMPROVMENT` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `ENGLISH_LEVEL_ID` INT NULL ,
  `LEVEL_ID` INT NULL ,
  `DESIRED_POSITIONS` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `HR_COMMENT` TEXT NULL ,
  `EXPERT_COMMENT` TEXT NULL ,
  `FOREIGN_PASSPORT_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `SALARY_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `SSE_INFO_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `EXPERT_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `HR_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `TEACHER_NAME` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `FK_CANDIDATE_ENGLISH_LEVEL1` (`ENGLISH_LEVEL_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_LEVEL1` (`LEVEL_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_FOREIGN_PASSPORT1` (`FOREIGN_PASSPORT_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_SALARY1` (`SALARY_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_SSE_INFO1` (`SSE_INFO_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CANDIDATE_ENGLISH_LEVEL1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ENGLISH_LEVEL_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`ENGLISH_LEVEL` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_LEVEL1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LEVEL_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`LEVEL` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_FOREIGN_PASSPORT1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FOREIGN_PASSPORT_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`FOREIGN_PASSPORT` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_SALARY1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SALARY_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`SALARY` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_SSE_INFO1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SSE_INFO_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`SSE_INFO` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_HISTORY`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_HISTORY` (
  `ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `CANDIDATE_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_HISTORY_CANDIDATE1` (`CANDIDATE_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_HISTORY_CANDIDATE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CANDIDATE_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`CANDIDATE` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_CHANGES`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_CHANGES` (
  `ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `FIELD` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `CHANGED_VALUE` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_HISTORY_has_CANDIDATE_CHANGES`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_HISTORY_has_CANDIDATE_CHANGES` (
  `CANDIDATE_HISTORY_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `CANDIDATE_CHANGES_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CANDIDATE_HISTORY_ID`, `CANDIDATE_CHANGES_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_CANDIDATE_HISTORY_has_CANDIDATE_CHANGES_CANDIDATE_CHANGES1` (`CANDIDATE_CHANGES_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_HISTORY_has_CANDIDATE_CHANGES_CANDIDATE_HISTORY1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CANDIDATE_HISTORY_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_HISTORY` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CANDIDATE_HISTORY_has_CANDIDATE_CHANGES_CANDIDATE_CHANGES1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CANDIDATE_CHANGES_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CVM`.`CANDIDATE_CHANGES` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In SQL workbench its all ok, but using maven-sql-plugin it failed to create table candidate_history_has_candidate_changes. All names are less than 64 symbols. Please, help!

Comment: Can I see CVM.Candidate?

Comment: Does any of those tables already exist and has data in it? I can't find anything obviously suspicious about the tables, so it might be that one of the tables already exists and isn't created properly.

Comment: Table candidate is exists, but havent any data

Comment: Can you verify the table and see if the columns are defined correctly. More specifically, can you control if cvm.candidate.id is INT(11) UNSIGNED (the UNSIGNED bit is important for a reference to work).

Comment: You say that however it written in script INT(11) UNSIGNED it may be not this after creating table?

Comment: The command CREATE IF NOT EXIST states that it will only execute the command in the script if the table doesn't already exist. If it exists, the command is ignored. If cvm.candidate was created with a prior version of the script (which contains incompatible definitions for referencing), then you have to dump that table and re-create it using the script.

Comment: Thanks, i find mistakes in both candidate_history and candidate_changes, they created previously with simple INT ids

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down the possible causes, starting with a simple `create table`. Try creating this simple table with and without backtick quotes in case the plugin isn't handling them properly.

Check you are logging in as the same user in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

See if there are any leftovers from the tables. CREATE IF NOT EXIST does nothing if the tables already exist. (see asker's comments for more info).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possible answers here:
http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/